# Сериализация и шифрование в XML c#

Tags: c#, xml

Столкнулся с непонятной мне проблемой. У меня есть следующие классы для сериализации.

```
  [Serializable]
public class Exercise
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Theme { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public Exercise()
    {

    }

[Serializable]
public class Option
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IdExercise { get; set; }
    public bool IsTest { get; set; }

    public Option()
    {

    }
}
```

И есть методы сериализации с шифрованием и десериализации с дешифрование соответственно.

```
  public static void SerializerXml<T>(string file, List<T> list, SymmetricAlgorithm key)
    {
        using (Stream ss = File.Open(file, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ss, key.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(ss, list);
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<T> DeSerializerXml<T>(string file, List<T> list, SymmetricAlgorithm key)
    {
        using (Stream sl = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(sl, key.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
                list = (List<T>)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sl);
                return list;
            }
        }
    }
```

Как итог после сериализации, создается файл XML, но в конце файла, после корневого элемента добавляются посторонние символы. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить и откуда вообще это появилось. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `xmlSerializer.Serialize(ss, list)` - здесь должен быть `cs`. Аналогично при десериализации.

Comment: Я так понимаю, это криптопоток записывает служебную информацию.

Comment: Да, все верно. Спасибо, все получилось.